# HTML form show fields depending on drop down selected

Tags: jquery, html

Having an issue here. Trying to make certain fields appear depending on what has been selected in a drop down box. I"ve had a look on stack and have tried editing the code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/tarleton/p8ARq/15/
to work with mine. I cannot seem to get it to work...total newbie here so any help appreciated.

```
$("select").change(function () {
    // hide all optional elements
    $('.optional').css('display','none');

    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
        if($(this).name() == "test") {
            $('.test').css('display','block');
        } else if($(this).val() == "test2") {
            $('.test2').css('display','block');
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form class="contact" name="contact" action="#" method="post">
       <div id="styled-select">
           <select>
            <option name="test" value="Option 1" >Referral</option>
              <option name="test2"value="Option 2">Other</option>
              </select>
       </div>
          <input class="optional test" name="revealtest" style="display:none;" class="hidden-txt">

       <input class="optional other" name="revealtest2" value="" style="display:none;" class="hidden-txt">

</form>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for this. 

I know this is lazy however I'm looking to make this into a pretty extensive forms with lots of if variables. Anyone know of a a GUI that I can use to save manual code? I've tried doing a bit of a search however nothing I have come across has this functionality

Answer (score 1):

There is not `.name` for jQuery.

You can use `.attr()`

```
if($(this).attr('name')
```

and `class` can be applied to `div` or other tag.

so specify what to select as below,

```
$('input.test2').css('display','block'); 
$('input.test').css('display','block');
```

Also wrap all `class` inside single `class` attribute and also remove `inline style` because in `jQuery` you are also doing hiding using `.hide()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I came up with http://jsfiddle.net/burn123/p8ARq/34/

The major thing that I noticed was that you had `style="display:hide"`. Because this it is an inline style, it won't be easily removed. You also had an unnecessary `optional` class that added a second `display:none` to the element. So I removed both of those and set the CSS to

```
.other, .referral {
  display:none;
}
```

So the `display` was only toggled once. Your jQuery was fine for the most part. You needed to have the referral set to `$(this).val()` like you did for `other`. Also, you need an ending `else` if you want the textboxes to hide when you choose something else. I used `fadeToggle` instead of `css("display", "block")` to give it a little bit of transition as well. There is probably a more code effective way of accomplishing this, but I'm still pretty new to jquery ;)

Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to hide all your controls by using `$("your_control").hide()` or `$("your_control").show()`, I just update your sample at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8ARq/38/)